# Make a dns resolver with node js

Tags: node.js, dns

is there any way i can make a DNS resolver with Node JS that will resolve every domain name as for example 0.0.0.0? I have looked at the official Node JS DNS module docs but it is confusing and i cant find a straight answer. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to write that software? Except if it is for learning, there is no reason to reinvent things, `dnsmasq` should be more than adequate for that need.

Comment: yes it is for learning

Answer (score 0):

there are exemples everywhere :)

if you want to resolve a domain to an ip adress :

```
let dns = require('dns');
dns.resolve("google.com", function(err, data) {
    console.log(data)
});
// > e.g. Array [ '216.58.213.78' ]
```

Comment: That's not really what i mean, what I want is a dns server where i can go to google.com and it will request the ip from the server and then send back 0.0.0.0 or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. If you want to look up domain names and get names the Node DNS API is the tool. You don't say what you found confusing, but if you google around there are plenty of examples out there.

If you want to start from scratch to build your own DNS server, use the [TCP](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) network API and [UDP](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html) socket API. You'll also want to read the [DNS RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1034). If you found Nodes DNS API confusing, then this route (no pun intended) is probably not for you.

If you just want to host dns w/ node and manipulate traffic, then you can use a library such as [bindns](https://github.com/primitybio/bindns).